# Facebook iOS - Error when disallowing app on SSO and then uninstalling app

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I've developed an app with Facebook integration and I'm testing multiple failed login scenarios. Then I've saw one that is stucking me.

The scenario is:

1. User have iOS 6 SSO configured with his account.
2. Then user open the app and DO NOT authorize it.
3. Then user removes his Facebook account from iOS.

The result:

App is getting stuck because it is getting the unauthorized information and I cannot change this anymore because the Facebook account isn't integrated to iOS anymore.

My problem is:

I need to know if the user has set his Facebook credentials on iOS (Settings > Facebook).
How can I know it? I've searched Facebook documentation and could not find out.

Here is my code:

```
+ (void)initFacebook:(void (^)(int))initResult
{
    NSLog(@"init: activeSession.state = %i", FBSession.activeSession.state);

    [FBSession renewSystemCredentials:^(ACAccountCredentialRenewResult result, NSError *error) {
        if (result == ACAccountCredentialRenewResultFailed) {
            //User has changed his password and must update his iOS login credentials
            NSLog(@"sync: ACAccountCredentialRenewResultFailed -- error.code = %i", error.code);

            //Display some message to user…           

            //Get rid of the token with wrong credentials
            [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
            FBSession.activeSession = [[FBSession alloc] init];

            initResult(1);
        }
        else if (result == ACAccountCredentialRenewResultRejected) {
            //User has unauthorized my App in Settings > Facebook
            NSLog(@"sync: ACAccountCredentialRenewResultRejected -- error.code = %i", error.code);

            //Display some message to user…

            //Get rid of the token with wrong credentials            
            [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
            FBSession.activeSession = [[FBSession alloc] init];

            initResult(2);
        }
        else if (result == ACAccountCredentialRenewResultRenewed) {
            //Everything is fine with iOS credentials
            NSLog(@"sync: ACAccountCredentialRenewResultRenewed -- error.code = %i", error.code);

            //Just to be sure that the session state is right
            if (FBSession.activeSession.state == FBSessionStateCreated ||
                FBSession.activeSession.state == FBSessionStateCreatedOpening ||
                FBSession.activeSession.state == FBSessionStateCreatedTokenLoaded) {

                //Open the active session
                [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:@[@"basic_info", @"user_photos"]
                                                   allowLoginUI:YES
                                              completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState status, NSError *error) {
                                                  NSLog(@"opensession: activeSession.state = %i", FBSession.activeSession.state);


                                              }];
            }
        }
    }];
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you're looking for your info in wrong place.
Quit looking Facebook SDK docs and go to [Social.framework documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Social/Reference/Social_Framework/_index.html) for that.
These are about system facebook accounts.

Comment: Thanks!! I could use [SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook] to verify if the SSO for Facebook is set on iOS 6.

Anyway, I have wrote again my routine and this is no longer needed.

Now after I sync my credentials from iOS, if the return state is ACAccountCredentialRenewResultRejected I try to open the session again but with facebook SDK [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions] and this refreshes the token if it was stuck.

Thanks for the help!